# Scala partial initialization of a case class

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I've been building some tests based on manually initialized case classes. The issue is, my case class is pretty big - all types are Optional. I'd like to initialize it with only a few fields (other are null). Is this possible. So, for example

```
case class Employee(Name:Option(String), Age:Option(Int), Designation:Option(String), Salary:Option(Int), ZipCode:Option(Int))
val EmployeesData = Seq( Employee("Anto",   21, "Software Engineer", 2000, 56798))
val Employee_DataFrame = EmployeesData.toDF
Employee_DataFrame.show()
```

Would be full init, but I'd like to do e.g.,

```
val EmployeesData = Seq( Employee("Anto"))
```

Or event better, do this for specific keys somehow. Any ideas?

Comment: Just add default values to class parameters? 
`case class Employee(name: Option[String] = None, age: Option[Int] = None, ...)`

Comment: Oh boy, I'm facepalming so hard right now .. thanks @Dima - feel free to post this as an answer, it's definitely what I was missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by Dima:

Give every field a default value:

```scala
case class Employee(
  name: Option[String] = None,
  age: Option[Int] = None,
  ...
)
```

Now you can do: `Employee().copy(name = Some("Name"))`.

Comment: Dima, when you want to post this yourself let me know and I'll remove this answer.